# delete text file java doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse

Here's example:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Charbel\\Desktop\\Dictionary.txt";
    String temppath = "C:\\Users\\Charbel\\Desktop\\temp.txt";
    File file = new File(path);
    File tempfile = new File(temppath);
    int numl = search("x");
    int countL = 0;
    String line;

    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temppath));

        while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(countL != numl){

            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();

            }

        countL++;
        }
        bf.close();
        bw.close();
        file.delete();
        boolean successful = tempfile.renameTo(file);
        System.out.println(successful);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
    }



    }
    public static int search(String name) 
    {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Charbel\\Desktop\\Dictionary.txt";
        int countL = 0;
        String line;

        try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
        {
                int indexfound = line.indexOf(name);

                if (indexfound == 0) {
                   return countL;
                }
                countL++;
        }

        bf.close();
    }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
        }

        return -1;

    }
    }
```

Hello there .. i am trying to read the line of a specific string in a text file , get the number of its line , then copy all the data in the file to another text file except the line of the string 
the code is sometimes working 100% and sometimes no ; I go to my desktop I see both files the temp and the original one without deleting and renaming it 
i think i have a problem in deleting the file what do you think coders ?

Comment: Just in case I would consider taking all the .close() calls to a `finally {}` block, that way you make sure you return all the resources you asked for to the OS

Comment: is the file opened?  what error EXACTLY?

Comment: In case it helps, `file.delete()` returns a boolean, `true` if delete was successful, `false` if not.  If you're using more recent jdk you can try the Files class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html

Comment: there is no error but the variable "successful" gave me few times true and the rest of time its false , i think the file isn't deleting

Comment: Are you sure it's always writing? I think if you don't write anything on the file, I'm not sure if calling it inside BufferedReader automatically creates the file, but I know that just calling the File object doesn't create it in the file system.

Also, maybe it's a time thing, you could try a while(file.delete()); and see if it never loops infinitely.

Comment: try file.close() befor file.delete()

Comment: am sure it is always writing , i checked the temp file after the debug

Comment: there is no method close for files

Comment: Just glancing at your code, but don't you want to delete `tempfile` (and not `file`) ?

Comment: i want to delete the original and rename the temp , i need the temp file

Comment: Did you check if it's a time problem? You could try with the while(file.delete()) or something like Thread.sleep() just to check it out, then find a better solution.

Comment: i tried it , i get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when the search method find name(actually "x"),don't reach the line `bf.close()`, so bf is still opened and  file.delete() fails.
So, you need to modify the search method to the below:

```
public static int search(String name) {
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Charbel\\Desktop\\Dictionary.txt";
    int countL = 0;
    String line;

    BufferedReader bf = null;
    try {
        bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int indexfound = line.indexOf(name);

            if (indexfound == 0) {
                return countL;
            }
            countL++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
    }
    finally {
        if(bf != null) {
            try {
                bf.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ignored) {}
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```